SecurityException One of RECEIVER_EXPORTED or RECEIVER_NOT_EXPORTED should be specified
I have been trying to solve this error came from Google Play Pre-launch report for a while. I am using DJI SDK for my app and looks like the error comes from it. I got this error after I set my Android SDK from 33 to 35 that Google force me to do so. Any ideas are welcome.
Exception java.lang.SecurityException: com.kuzu.drone: One of RECEIVER_EXPORTED or RECEIVER_NOT_EXPORTED should be specified when a receiver isn't being registered exclusively for system broadcasts
  at android.os.Parcel.createExceptionOrNull (Parcel.java:3183)
  at android.os.Parcel.createException (Parcel.java:3167)
  at android.os.Parcel.readException (Parcel.java:3150)
  at android.os.Parcel.readException (Parcel.java:3092)
  at android.app.IActivityManager$Stub$Proxy.registerReceiverWithFeature (IActivityManager.java:5860)
  at android.app.ContextImpl.registerReceiverInternal (ContextImpl.java:1853)
  at android.app.ContextImpl.registerReceiver (ContextImpl.java:1793)
  at android.app.ContextImpl.registerReceiver (ContextImpl.java:1781)
  at android.content.ContextWrapper.registerReceiver (ContextWrapper.java:757)
  at dji.midware.usb.P3.UsbAccessoryService.registerAoaReceiver
  at dji.midware.dgh.fdd
  at dji.sdksharedlib.fdd.fdd
  at dji.sdk.sdkmanager.DJISDKManager.initParams
  at dji.sdk.sdkmanager.DJISDKManager.initSDKManager
  at dji.sdk.sdkmanager.DJISDKManager.registerApp
  at dji.sdk.sdkmanager.DJISDKManager.access$1400
  at dji.sdk.sdkmanager.DJISDKManager$8.onDownloadSuccess
  at dji.internal.jhg.fdd.fdd
  at dji.sdk.sdkmanager.DJISDKManager.lambda$registerApp$2
  at dji.sdk.sdkmanager.DJISDKManager$$Lambda$4.run
  at dji.sdksharedlib.dgh.dgh$fdd.run
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:644)
  at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:1012)
Caused by android.os.RemoteException: Remote stack trace:
  at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.registerReceiverWithFeature (ActivityManagerService.java:14467)
  at android.app.IActivityManager$Stub.onTransact (IActivityManager.java:2648)
  at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.onTransact (ActivityManagerService.java:2822)
  at android.os.Binder.execTransactInternal (Binder.java:1500)
  at android.os.Binder.execTransact (Binder.java:1444)


Make sure you are on the latest version of their SDK.

I have the same problem. I contacted the developer support and this was their answer:

MSDK is currently not compatible with Android 14. We plan to adapt it in the next version, which is expected to be released in November.


Google has provided an extension option for users who are temporarily unable to adapt to Android 14, allowing a delay until November at the latest. We will strive to release a version compatible with Android 14 before the final deadline given by Google.

You can compile the app by setting "compileSdkVersion" and "targetSdkVersion" to API 33. The way to do that is to install an earlier version of Android studio and compile your app with it. For example, Android studio Jellyfish 2023.3.1 Patch 2 lets you do it (it will just underline the two variables and say there is a newer version available, but it will let you run the code).
I successfully installed my app on Android 14 this way, but I still have problems with the register app method. I think it has something to do with deprecated permissions. Could you share your version if you manage to register the app API 33? I also tried to disable permissions that the app does not need, like making phone calls and such..
Now I'm gonna try to run the latest basic example posted by DJI on (https://github.com/dji-sdk/Mobile-SDK-Android) and see how that goes. The compile and target API is set to 31, so idk if I will be able to run it. Also, I didn't have much luck with their examples in the past.

Hi Luka,
I also contacted DJI and unfortunately they said they no longer support MSDK v4. And I am trying to integrate MSDK v5 into our project. Are you using V4 or V5? Thanks.

Hello, I'm using MSDK v4 (since Matrice 210v2 drones do not support MSDK v5). From the response I got, they are planning to upgrade version 4.17 to support Android 14. It does not make sense not to update it, since the all the older drones are not supported by MSDK v5.

This is what Android Docs says about the context-registered receivers in the Behaviour changes of Android 14 (API level 34)

Runtime-registered broadcasts receivers must specify export behavior
Apps and services that target Android 14 (API level 34) or higher and use context-registered receivers are required to specify a flag to indicate whether or not the receiver should be exported to all other apps on the device: either RECEIVER_EXPORTED or RECEIVER_NOT_EXPORTED, respectively. This requirement helps protect apps from security vulnerabilities by leveraging the features for these receivers introduced in Android 13.


Exception for receivers that receive only system broadcasts
If your app is registering a receiver only for system broadcasts through
Context#registerReceiver methods, such as Context#registerReceiver(), then it shouldn't specify a flag when registering the receiver.

Hence,
To allow the broadcast receiver to receive broadcasts from other apps, register the receiver with RECEIVER_EXPORTED flag.
And, to register a broadcast receiver that does not receive broadcasts from other apps, including system apps, register the receiver with RECEIVER_NOT_EXPORTED flag.

And if you think that this error comes from a third-party SDK or library, you should check for latest version updates of that SDK or library, or consider contacting their developers or forums for the fix of this update.
Hope this helps in solving your problem.

We are actually using the DJI Mobile SDK which is causing the error. Thank you.
